# IOS9. UITextView contentOffset changes when you change the font

Tags: ios, uikit, ios9

When I change the value of font is called `_setContentOffsetWithoutRecordingscrollposition`, which sets the `contentOffset` value to `0.0`. How to avoid it?

In previous versions this was not.

Comment: Wait. That's not included in public API, right ? There is `setContentOffset` only.

Comment: Have you tried saving and restoring the contentOffset yourself?

Comment: I use contentSize to set the cursor in the middle of the UITextView. I set in the contentOffset my value. At the time when I change the font contentSize is not changed, but there is a call _setContentOffsetWithoutRecordingscrollposition, which changes the value of contentOffset. I can set my value in contentOffset, but earlier it was not required. Want to know your opinion how to do this right?

Comment: Did you try doing what @jtbandes said?

Comment: Yes, it works. But in IOS8 it wasn't needed. I'm not sure what I doing correctly?